# Can you trap the ender dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yes i want to trap the ender dragon. I run a server of maybe 20 people and none of us what to kill it, (its a nice pet) but we have a few people that actually want to put their base in the End.

Is it possible to trap the dragon so that it can be kept safe *maybe in a corner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some options and some considerations:

- You can build in the end while the Dragon is still alive as long as you build far enough from the main island.
- Alternatively, you can lead the dragon far away from the main island and store the dragon in unloaded chunks. Then you can build at the main island at will. Just make sure no one walks in the direction of the dragon, because it will be loaded again and it will escape (it'll make its way back to the main island).
- Putting your base at The End without killing the dragon is not very practical, because you have to kill yourself to go back.
- **You can actually trap** a dying dragon with pistons that constantly move (on a clock). It is **very** hard to do that for alive dragon, though (especially in survival).
- Here is a very cool video showing how to build a dragon XP farm. It also shows how to temporary store the dragon in far-away chunks, and the 'trap with pistons' trick:

Comment: "Alternatively, you can lead the dragon far away from the main island and store the dragon in unloaded chunks". I don't think this part works as of 1.9, as the game will spawn a new dragon .

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki for minecraft](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Ender_Dragon) says:

> They swoop at the player, destroying any blocks it passes through except obsidian, bedrock, or End Stone.

meaning that there is no material to effectively trap the dragon.

Comment: I have also see that it doesnt destroy 4 types of blocks being stone, ender stone, obsidian & bedrock

Comment: @Flaunting The dragon just passes right through any blocks that don't get destroyed.

Comment: @Flaunting I'm pretty sure that stone gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are an admin on this server ("I run a server of maybe 20 people") and you have all admin privileges, this is probably the best way to trap the enderdragon without having to lose sight of it (as in the previous answer, where the dragon would be led to an unloaded chunk, thus losing its use as a pet)

Use an inventory-editing software to create a potion of Slowness V that lasts indefinitely. Slowness V will completely immobilize the dragon. Hit the dragon with the potion, then build a glass box around it or something. Protect the glass box with admin perms. Voila, a "a trapped dragon that can be kept safe *maybe in a corner".

Here is a useful link to creating indefinite custom potions, credits to Sethbling.
http://sethbling.com/downloads/mcedit-filters/modifypotions/

Comment: Potion effects don't work on the ender dragon.

Answer (score -1):

end stone does not get destroyed. their is no possible way and if you are building a farm build a portal to the end in one part and have them walk their. Just make sure if they hunt it they respawn it. Or you respawn it

Comment: End stone isn't destroyed, but it doesn't block the Dragon either; it is simply flown through like it was air.